# Building OpenSSH 8.2p1 on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, what flags should I configure it with?

Tags: 18.04, server, ssh, compiling, openssh

I need a newer version of OpenSSH on my home machine for remote work.

What flags should I pass to `./configure` to maintain the same level of configuration as my current OpenSSH (7.6p1), the one included in 18.04? I just want to make sure ssh works reliably and is compatible with my current version. Even a way to see what flags the standard version of OpenSSH was compiled with would be very helpful (I'm hoping to do better than just looking at what ssh is linked against like [this answer suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15622/output-compiler-options-from-ssh), though I suspect that's my best option).

These are all the flags `./configure -h` outputs:

```
Optional Packages:
  --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]
  --without-PACKAGE       do not use PACKAGE (same as --with-PACKAGE=no)
  --without-openssl       Disable use of OpenSSL; use only limited internal crypto **EXPERIMENTAL**
  --without-stackprotect  Don't use compiler's stack protection
  --without-hardening     Don't use toolchain hardening flags
  --without-rpath         Disable auto-added -R linker paths
  --with-cflags           Specify additional flags to pass to compiler
  --with-cflags-after     Specify additional flags to pass to compiler after configure
  --with-cppflags         Specify additional flags to pass to preprocessor
  --with-ldflags          Specify additional flags to pass to linker
  --with-ldflags-after    Specify additional flags to pass to linker after configure
  --with-libs             Specify additional libraries to link with
  --with-Werror           Build main code with -Werror
  --with-solaris-contracts Enable Solaris process contracts (experimental)
  --with-solaris-projects Enable Solaris projects (experimental)
  --with-solaris-privs    Enable Solaris/Illumos privileges (experimental)
  --with-osfsia           Enable Digital Unix SIA
  --with-zlib=PATH        Use zlib in PATH
  --without-zlib-version-check Disable zlib version check
  --with-ldns[=PATH]      Use ldns for DNSSEC support (optionally in PATH)
  --with-libedit[=PATH]   Enable libedit support for sftp
  --with-audit=module     Enable audit support (modules=debug,bsm,linux)
  --with-pie              Build Position Independent Executables if possible
  --with-security-key-builtin include builtin U2F/FIDO support
  --with-ssl-dir=PATH     Specify path to OpenSSL installation
  --without-openssl-header-check Disable OpenSSL version consistency check
  --with-ssl-engine       Enable OpenSSL (hardware) ENGINE support
  --with-prngd-port=PORT  read entropy from PRNGD/EGD TCP localhost:PORT
  --with-prngd-socket=FILE read entropy from PRNGD/EGD socket FILE (default=/var/run/egd-pool)
  --with-pam              Enable PAM support
  --with-pam-service=name Specify PAM service name
  --with-privsep-user=user Specify non-privileged user for privilege separation
  --with-sandbox=style    Specify privilege separation sandbox (no, capsicum, darwin, rlimit, seccomp_filter, systrace, pledge)
  --with-selinux          Enable SELinux support
  --with-kerberos5=PATH   Enable Kerberos 5 support
  --with-privsep-path=xxx Path for privilege separation chroot (default=/var/empty)
  --with-xauth=PATH       Specify path to xauth program
  --with-maildir=/path/to/mail    Specify your system mail directory
  --with-mantype=man|cat|doc  Set man page type
  --with-md5-passwords    Enable use of MD5 passwords
  --without-shadow        Disable shadow password support
  --with-ipaddr-display   Use ip address instead of hostname in $DISPLAY
  --with-default-path=    Specify default $PATH environment for server
  --with-superuser-path=  Specify different path for super-user
  --with-4in6             Check for and convert IPv4 in IPv6 mapped addresses
  --with-bsd-auth         Enable BSD auth support
  --with-pid-dir=PATH     Specify location of sshd.pid file
  --with-lastlog=FILE|DIR specify lastlog location common locations
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be running a 2-year-old OS that doesn't seem to meet your needs?

Comment: @user535733 that's a fair point but I don't want to reinstall 20.04 from scratch, I've done a lot of setting up that I don't want to go through. I think Canonical will release an upgrade path from 18.04 to 20.04 in July so I might upgrade then but for the time being it just seems safer to stick with 18.04.4.

Comment: Fair enough, just making sure. Lots of folks find themselves haywiring for the wrong reasons, so we ask.